# Derivation in SU(5) group theory

Tags: group-theory

I want to show

$$10\otimes10=5^*\oplus45^*\oplus50^*~~,$$

where

$$\varphi^{i}\equiv5,~~\varphi^{[ij]}\equiv10,~~\varphi^{\{ij\}}\equiv15,~~\varphi^{i}_{j}\equiv24,~~\varphi^{[ij]}_{k}\big(Tr(\varphi^{[ij]}_{k})=0 \big)\equiv45.$$

I got these numbers from the source material I'm looking at, and I do completely understand what they mean regarding the degrees of freedom, so my question is two-fold:

(1) How to I discover the 50 representation of SU(5) when I don't already know it?

(2) How do I start with $10\otimes10\equiv\varphi^{[ij]}\eta^{[kl]}=T^{[ij][kl]}$ and then start cutting it into pieces?  My material says "separate the traceless part" and, other than that is the $5^*$ piece, I don't know what it means to "separate" or what the algorithmic operations are for converting direct products to direct sums in the multiplication of representations.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The $50^*$ representation is the traceless part of $\varphi^{[ij]}_{[klm]}.$ You discover it by doing this very problem.
2. The way to get this into the appropriate form is by lowering the indices on one of the $10$'s. Since it's $SU(5),$ two antisymmetric upper indices turn into three antisymmetric lower indices, so the $10\times 10$ looks like $\varphi^{[ij]}_{[klm]}.$ There's nothing to do here regarding symmetry, so it's just a matter of separating out the traces. Taking the first trace gives us something that looks like $\varphi^{i}_{[kl]}.$ Then separating out the trace of that gives something that looks like $\varphi_k,$ i.e. a $5^*.$ The trace-free part of $\varphi^{i}_{[kl]}$ is just an upside-down version of what you wrote down as the $45,$ so it's the $45^*.$  The remaining fully traceless part of $\varphi^{[ij]}_{[klm]}$ is the $50^*.$

Comment: Thanks!  I was missing that the antisymmetric SU(5) tensor has five indices.  I totally follow what you did, and I got the $5^*$, $45^*$, and I see that the remaining part is like you say.  However, I am still not sure what "separate the trace" means.  I can get the numbers by examing the two traces, but how do I write it as a sum?  Also, how do I know the remaining piece is $50^*$ and not just $50$?  How can I write $5^*\oplus45^*\oplus50^*$ as a sum of three tensors like what I have on the LHS with $10\otimes10=\varphi^{[ij]}\eta^{[kl]}$?  Thank you very much!!!

Comment: For the $50^*,$ that's just a naming convention. For any representation, there's a conjugate representation with upper and lower indices switched.  The ones with more lower indices are starred and ones with more upper indices are unstarred. Note also this naming convention can cause ambiguities: there's no reason to rule out that by some combinatorial accident we have two completely different (i.e. not related by conjugation) irreps that have the same dimension.

Comment: As for the question about the trace, first I think you're taking the $\varphi^{[ij]} \eta^{[kl]}$ thing a bit too literally. Really you should just write it like $\varphi^{[ij][kl]}.$ The elements of a tensor product space aren't all tensor products of elements of the factors, there are more degrees of freedom than that.

Comment: But onto the main question, Let's look at the (reducible) 50-dimensional representation that acts on $\varphi^{[ij]}_k.$ We can write the object as $$ \delta^j_k\varphi^{[il]}_l/N + (\varphi^{[ij]}_k-\varphi^{[il]}_l/N),$$ i.e. as a trace plus a trace free part. You can see that each transforms independently, (just as you could see that symmetric and antisymmetric parts would if there were anything left to symmetrize here). This translates into that $50$ breaking up (in the appropriate basis) into a $5$ and a $45$ block.